# Como Bloquear um button

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tenho um sistema onde tem partidas cadastradas e o usuário logado tenta acertar os resultados dessas partidas. Cada partida tem um `id` de cadastro que está com o nome (jogo) no banco de dados.

Minha duvida é: como eu faço com que o usuário só consiga apostar uma vez nesse jogo? Exemplo: o usuário aposta na partida 1 aí logo depois ele não consegue mais apostar nela novamente. Cada aposta possui um botão <kbd>apostar</kbd>. Queria fazer com que esse botão ficasse impedido de ser clicado se o usuário já tiver apostado ou aparecer um script onde diga que o usuário já apostou nessa partida. Segue o código da aposta:

apostar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");
if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])){

}else{
   echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Aréa Restrita.');
   window.location.href='/bolao/index.php';</script>";
}

$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$saldo="SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE email= '$email'";
$exe= mysqli_query($conexao, $saldo);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe);

$btnApostar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnApostar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnApostar){
   include_once ("../conn/conexao.php");
   $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

   $aposta = "INSERT INTO tb_aposta(apostacasa, apostafora, valor, data, usuario, jogo)VALUES(
   '".$dados['apostacasa']."',
   '".$dados['apostafora']."',
   '".$dados['valor']."',
   '".$dados['data']."',
   '".$_SESSION['email']."',
   '".$dados['jogo']."'
   )";
   $r_aposta = mysqli_query($conexao, $aposta) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
   $verificacao = "SELECT * FROM  tb_jogos WHERE jogo=".$dados['jogo'];
   $exe= mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conexao, $verificacao));
   $email=$_SESSION['email'];
   $saldo=$linha['saldo'];
   $valor=$_POST['valor'];
   // var_dump($exe);
   if (($valor) > ($saldo)){
      echo
      "<script>
      alert('Voce nao possui saldo para realizar a aposta.')
      window.location = 'apostar.php';
      </script>";
   }else{

      if(($dados['apostacasa'] == $exe['placarcasa']) && ($dados['apostafora'] == $exe['placarfora'])){

         $up = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE tb_usuario SET saldo=saldo+'$valor' WHERE email = '$email' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

         echo "<script> alert('Voce acertou, parabéns')
         window.location.href='apostar.php';
         </script>";

         ;

      }else{ //se estiver errado irá diminuir o valor apostado

         $up = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE tb_usuario SET saldo=saldo-'$valor' WHERE email = '$email' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

         echo "<script> alert('Voce errou, tente novamente')
         window.location.href='apostar.php';
         </script>";
      }

   }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
   <title>Lance Web</title>
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
   <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   <style type="text/css">
   /*Aqui deixa a imagem de fundo responsiva*/
   body{ 
      background: url(../img/principal.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
   }

   #font{
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
   }

   .img-responsive {
      max-width:250px;
      max-height:150px;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- nav e o menu -->   
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Aqui e como ira aparece em um telefone -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- Aqui no span, são os 3 pontos ao abrir em um telefone -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Voltar</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do saldo -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a>Saldo&nbsp; R$<?php echo $linha['saldo']; ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="apostar.php">Apostar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="historico.php">Histórico<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="ranking.php">Ranking<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="loja/loja.php">Loja<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do sair -->  
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="sair.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></a></li>
         </ul>

      </div><!-- fim da div collapse, ela faz com que abra um menu ao aumentar o site -->
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<?php
include("../conn/conexao.php");
//ORDER BY serve para organizar os dados de acordo com o que voce quiser
$buscar="SELECT * FROM tb_jogos ORDER BY jogo DESC";
$exe= mysqli_query($conexao, $buscar) or die ("OCORREU UM ERRO AO MOSTRAR OS DADOS");
//começo da tabela
echo "<br><br><div class='container'>
<table class='table table-inverse'>
<thead>
<tr bgcolor='#222222' align='center'>
<th><font color='white'>Codigo Partida</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Time Casa</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Placar</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Time Fora</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Placar</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Lance</font></th>
<th><font color='white'></font></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</div>";


while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)){
   echo "<form class='form-group' action='' method='post'>
   <input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='data' id='id_01' readonly>
   <tbody>
   <tr bgcolor='#222222'>
   <td><font color='white'><input type='int' class='form-control' name='jogo' maxlength='1' value=".$linha['jogo']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'></font></td>
   <td><font color='white'>".$linha['casa']."</font></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostacasa' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><font color='white'>".$linha['fora']."</font></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostafora' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='valor' maxlength='5' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><input class='btn btn-success submit-botao' type='submit' value='Apostar' name='btnApostar'></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </form>";
}
?>

<script> // script da data atual...
var today = new Date();
var dy = today.getDate();
var mt = today.getMonth()+1;
var yr = today.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('id_01').value= yr+"-"+mt+"-"+dy;
</script>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa buscar no banco os jogos que o usuário já apostou e tratar isso na hora de construir as tabelas.

Minha sugestão é alterar a linha de consulta abaixo:

```
$buscar="SELECT * FROM tb_jogos ORDER BY jogo DESC";
```

para:

```
$buscar="SELECT *, a.jogo as id_jogo FROM tb_jogos a LEFT JOIN tb_aposta b ON (a.jogo = b.jogo) GROUP BY id_jogo ORDER BY id_jogo DESC";
```

No `while`, adicione as linhas logo no início:

```
$desativa_btn = "type='submit'";
if($linha['usuario'] == $_SESSION['email']){
   $desativa_btn = "disabled='disabled' type='button'";
}
```

e na linha do botão, adicione `$desativa_btn`:

```
<td><input ".$desativa_btn." class='btn btn-success submit-botao' value='Apostar' name='btnApostar'></td>
```

O `while` ficará assim:

```
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($exe)){
   $desativa_btn = "type='submit'";
   if($linha['usuario'] == $_SESSION['email']){
      $desativa_btn = "disabled='disabled' type='button'";
   }

   echo "<form class='form-group' action='' method='post'>
   <input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='data' id='id_01' readonly>
   <tbody>
   <tr bgcolor='#222222'>
   <td><font color='white'><input type='int' class='form-control' name='jogo' maxlength='1' value=".$linha['id_jogo']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'></font></td>
   <td><font color='white'></font></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostacasa' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><font color='white'></font></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostafora' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='valor' maxlength='5' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><input ".$desativa_btn." class='btn btn-success submit-botao' value='Apostar' name='btnApostar'></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </form>";
}
```

Com essas alterações, o botão <kbd>Apostar</kbd> deverá ficar desabilitado para as apostas registradas no banco com a `$_SESSION['email']` do usuário.

Comment: teria como me explicar a parte de busca no banco de dados? não entendi muito bem como substituir no meu código, o que seria esse a.jogo e b.jogo? no meu banco e no código só utilizo o jogo como o id  da partida

Comment: Oi @pherb! Cara, eu fiz assim: as duas tabelas estão correlacionadas pelo id do jogo no campo "jogo". Então eu fiz um "left join" pra relacionar uma tabela à outra puxando os jogos disponíveis na tabela "tb_jogos". Eu coloquei um alias para cada tabela com "a" e "b" respectivamente, e o "ON (a.jogo = b.jogo)" é para pegar da segunda tabela o mesmo código da primeira. Assim, o "while" irá detectar o código do jogo que o usuário possui na tabela "tb_aposta".

Comment: @pherb [continuando...]  Desta forma é possível saber se o usuário já apostou naquele id do jogo. A substituição é simples: é só trocar a sua query pela query sugerida e alterar o "while" como indiquei na resposta.

Comment: agora eu entendi, valeu mesmo, outra duvida, como faço para ao acerta eu jogar o valor de Vitoria ou Derrota para o campo Resultado no banco de dados? já tentei dar um update na tb_aposta mais quando dou o update ele atualiza todo os campos resultado

Comment: @pherb faz uma query `UPDATE tb_aposta SET resultado = 'vitoria' WHERE jogo = '$id_jogo' AND usuario = '$usuario'` quando acertar. Quando errar, a mesma coisa, só trocando `'vitoria'` por `'derrota'`... substituindo as respectivas variáveis (`$id_jogo`, `$usuario`) pelo que vc usa no código.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo, você criar uma tabela chamada por exemplo:
apostas_feitas, com id | id_usuario | id_jogo | apostado | status

cada clique de aposta realizada pelo usuario, vc salva nesta tabela, e verifica se se o mesmo usuario já apostou neste jogo, apartir dessa lógica, vc executa mais condições e verificações para deixar o sistema de apostas mais seguro, como data, ip e etc... Fica a seu critério. No meu caso eu faria dessa forma, já que não está sendo utilizado javascript.

Answer (score 0):

É só vc verificar no banco de apostas o id de quem esta apostando por exemplo

Primeiro consulte o banco com o id do usuário:

```
$query = "select * from apostas where id_usuario='$id_usuario'";
$result= $db->query($query); // aqui suas variáveis de conexão
$list= $result->row; // aqui para selecionar um célula
```

Depois crie um condição pra isso por exemplo:

```
<?php if($list['id_usuario'] != ''){ 
echo '<button type="submit">Apostar</button>';
}else{
echo 'Ops você ja apostou' OU '<button type="submit" disabled>Apostar</button>';
}
```

Assim utilizando o disabled o button se torna inativo, e dentro da condição ele vai verificar se o existe um valor dentro da tabela de apostas com o id do usuário.